# async call with c# only works with step by step debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous

So I'm currently building a Web Api with .NET, and using async calls with entity framework.

On my PUT endpoint for a controller, I'm trying to get whether the user already belongs to another level, or if he's in the DB at all, here's the controller code:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutCommittee(CommitteeViewModel committee)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (!User.IsInRole("Dean") && !User.IsInRole("Chair"))
            return Unauthorized();


        var user = await db.Users.Where(u => u.Cn == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (user == null) { return BadRequest("Your user does not exist"); }
        if (User.IsInRole("Dean"))
        {
            var college = await db.Colleges.Where(c => c.Dean.Cn == user.Cn).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (college == null) { return BadRequest("You're not a Dean of any college"); }
            committee.Name = _utils.getCollegeCommitteeName(college);

        }
        else
        {
            var department = await db.Departments.Where(d => d.Chair.Cn == user.Cn).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (department == null) { return BadRequest("You're not a Chair of any college"); }
            committee.Name = _utils.getDepartmentCommitteeName(department);
        }

        var model = await db.Commitees.Where(c => c.Name == committee.Name).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (model == null)
            return BadRequest("You have no committee");

        var tuple = await getUsers(committee);
        model.Users = tuple.Item1;
        if (model.Users == null)
            return BadRequest(tuple.Item2);

        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

And Here's the function that checks for the users:

```
        private async Task<Tuple<List<User>, string>> getUsers(CommitteeViewModel committee)
    {
        string error = "";
        List<User> users = new List<User>();
        var tuple = new Tuple<List<User>, string>(users, error);
        var role = await db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Committee").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        foreach (UserViewModel u in committee.Users)
        {
            var user = await db.Users.Where(us => us.Cn == u.Cn).FirstOrDefaultAsync();


            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Role.Name == "Chair" || user.Role.Name == "Dean")
                {
                    error = "User " +  user.Name + " is a " + user.Role.Name + " and cannot be member of a review committee";
                    return tuple;
                }

                users.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                user = _loginProvider.generateUser(u.Cn, role);
                db.Users.Add(user);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                users.Add(user);
            }
        }



        return tuple;
    }
```

I'm using a tuple since async method don't support OUT parameters, in case there's an error.

So the problem is that when I **delete** a user in my front-end (and then send a put request with the updated array), and I debug step by step, it does delete it, but when I don't, if I put a breakpoint at the try block, the variable model.Users contains the previous array (the original from the model), and this only happens when I delete a user from an array, and the weird thing is that it also happened when I wrote the code **synchronously**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We can not debug your code..... Please narrow down your problem and post a smaller code...

Comment: If this happens for asynchronous and synchronous then it's not an a sync issue.  Are you sure you're updating your model from the UI?

Comment: Yes, the ViewModel that appears in the debug process does include the changes that I want (deleting a user). The line that seems suspicios to me is the async getting of the Committee model variable, since the collection Users resets to what it previosuly had, even after the getUsers() function has been called

Answer (score -1):

Just remember... Async methods running back server, so if you have proccess that need run first you need to replace async method for a simple one. Trying it and I´m sure you can solve it.